# Gyp: generate x64 Visual Studio solution

Tags: 64-bit, gyp

After generating a .sln and .vcxproj from the gyp file below msbuild fails with

> "C:\proj\test\test.sln" (default target) (1) ->
>   (ValidateSolutionConfiguration target) ->
>   C:\proj\test\test.sln.metaproj : error MSB4126: The specified soluti
>   on configuration "Default|X64" is invalid. Please specify a valid
>   solution conf iguration using the Configuration and Platform
>   properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Sol ution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
>   /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properti es blank to use the
>   default solution configuration. [C:\proj\test\test.sln]

how do I make gyp generate a Default|x64 solution?

```
  {
    'targets': [
      {
        'target_name': 'test',
        'type': 'executable',
        'sources': [
          'test.cpp',          
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need to have declared target configuration and use it as a default value of `target_default`, similar to this:

```
{
    'target_defaults': {
        'default_configuration': 'Release_x64',
        'configurations':
        {
            'Debug': {
                # configuration specific settings
            },
            'Release': {
                # configuration specific settings
            },
            'Debug_x64': {
                'inherit_from': ['Debug'],
                'msvs_configuration_platform': 'x64',
            },
            'Release_x64': {
                'inherit_from': ['Release'],
                'msvs_configuration_platform': 'x64',
            },
        },
    },

    'targets': [
        {
            'target_name': 'test',
            'type': 'executable',
            'sources': [
                'test.cpp',          
            ],
        },
    ],
}
```